# Using key pairs from a file to replace values in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file with de-identified IDs as below:

`IDs.txt`

```
a   Michael
b   Elizabeth
c   Pierre
d   Nicholas
```

and I have a results file (assume they're weights):
`results.txt`

```
a   b   c   d
181   150   168   190
```

How do I replace the first row of my results file with their associated value in the `IDs.txt` file in python?

So far, I have

```py
dic = {}

with open("metadata.txt","r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        key_val = line.strip().split()
        dic[key_val[0]] = key_val[1]

resp = open("res.txt","r")

res_lis = resp.readline().split()
res_lis2 = []
for i in res_lis:
    res_lis2 = dic[res_lis]
```

How do I replace these key values from the first line of my `results.txt` with their associated value in the key pair of my dictionary?

Expected result would be:

```
Michael   Elizabeth   Pierre   Nicholas
181   150   168   190
```

Comment: `res_lis2 = [dic[r] for r in res_lis]`?

Comment: You will need to rewrite the entire results file replacing the first line in it with the values in `dic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic = {}

# Read IDs.txt and store the required dictionary in dic
with open("IDs.txt","r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        key_val = line.strip().split()
        dic[key_val[0]] = key_val[1]


# read the lines in result.txt file to res_lis,   
with open("result.txt","r") as resp:

    res_lis = resp.read().split("\n")

    # Store modified first line in res_lis2,
    res_lis2 = []
    for char in res_lis[0]:
        if char in dic.keys():
            res_lis2.append(dic[char])
        else:
            res_lis2.append(char)
    
    # replace first line of res_lis with modified line
    res_lis[0] = "".join(res_lis2)


# Open result.txt file as write the text with modified first line
with open("result.txt","w") as resp: 

    resp.write("\n".join(res_lis))
```

As @martineau also suggested, this rewrites the file with the aprropriate replacements

Answer (score 1):

I would use zip:

```
with open('IDs.txt', 'r') as f:
    ids = dict(line.split() for line in f)

with open('IDs_results.txt', 'r+') as f:
    res = dict(zip(*(line.split() for line in f)))
    f.seek(0)
    for row in zip(*((ids[k], v) for k, v in res.items())):
        print(*row, file=f)
```

Of course, if IDs and results always match and in same order then no need to use dictionaries at all. Also I rather not write in the same file.